# Cannot add style to ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add a style to `@Html.ValidationSummary()`, essentially I want display the error message as red and in a bold text, so I wrapped this in the following tag:

```
<p class="text-danger font-weight-bold">@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>
```

I used the `Bootstrap` class, but the result is even the same, and also the generated html by `@Html.ValidationSummary()` is added outside the `p` tag.

Someone has encountered a similar situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger font-weight-bold" })
```

That's using bootstrap's "text-danger" class, you could create your own in a css file, add whatever rules you want and apply it specifying the classname

Comment: I think so, give it a try ;) Anyways, you can create a sole css class with all the rules you need